# How to determine an equivalence class?

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let $A$ be a nonempty set and let $B$ be a fixed subset of $A$. A relations $R$ is defined on the power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ by $X\mathrel{R}Y$ if $X \cap B = Y \cap B$.

Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{1,3\}$. For a subset $X=\{2,3,4\}$, Determine the equivalence class $[X]$?

I have never heard of something like this. Any ideas to get started?

Answer (score 1):

Note $[X]=\{Y \subset A \mid X\mathrel{R}Y \}$. You have that $X \cap B=\{3\}$, thus \begin{equation*}
[X]=\{Y \subset A \mid Y \cap \{1,3\} = \{3\}\}
\end{equation*}
 What other subsets of $A$ can you construct that intersect with $B$ to get $\{3\}$? Some examples include $\{3,4\}$ and $\{2,3,5\}$.

Comment: Do you mean like a subset of A could be {1,3} and intersect with B to get {3}? How would this relate to being an equivalence class [X]?

Comment: For example, $Y=\{3,4\}$ has the property that $X \cap B = \{3\} = Y \cap B$, so $Y \in [X]$.

Comment: So any element of A paired with 3 will be apart of [X]?

Comment: No, $\{1,3\} \cap B \neq \{3\}$, so this set is not a member of $[X]$.  I've edited my answer to hopefully provide more clarity.